# How to unit test bit manipulation logic

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation, googletest

I have a method which converts RGBA to BGRA. Below is the method

```
unsigned int ConvertRGBAToBGRA(unsigned int v) {
    unsigned char r = (v)& 0xFF;
    unsigned char g = (v >> 8) & 0xFF;
    unsigned char b = (v >> 16) & 0xFF;
    unsigned char a = (v >> 24) & 0xFF;
    return (a << 24) | (r << 16) | (g << 8) | b;
};
```

How can I unit test this nicely? Is there a way I can read back the bits and unit test this method somehow?

I am using [googletests](https://github.com/google/googletest)

Comment: Can't you just input 0x12345678 and check the output 0x12785634 ? This should be convincing enough...

Comment: I would say you don't need access to the bits.  You just need test input values and test expected output values, all of which are unsigned ints.  Then you just compare your expected output values to the actual values returned by your function.

Comment: @harold Oh, there is a method to do this without having to deal with this unnecessary bit manipulation? I would like to see the logic. May be I put up a separate question for this

Comment: Also, if you put in the 5 constants `0xAAAAAAAA, 0xCCCCCCCC, 0xF0F0F0F0, 0xFF00FF00, 0xFFFF0000` then those 5 unit tests are exhaustive under the assumption that your function implements a bit-permutation (which is not a completely safe assumption, but it may be useful to you anyway)

Comment: Those 5 test cases actually let you read off the indices of where every bit in the result came from. The 5 bits every index are spread across the 5 results though, so the first result holds the least significant bits of every index and so on, not super convenient but that explains how it is an exhaustive test under the assumption that the function is a bit-permutation. You could also convert the result to a list of indexes and test it that way.

Comment: Unrelated but `unsigned int` isn't guaranteed to be 32 bits wide, which I assume you want here. Consider using `uint32_t` instead, it's more straightforward. Bonus point, it's shorter to write.

Comment: Thanks for that tip @Debaug. That is a v good point.

Comment: @harold I made https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71442595/how-to-replace-manual-bit-manipulation-by-bit-permute-step if you like to propose answer for how to use `bit_permute_step`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inspired by @Yves Daoust's comment, why can't you just write a series of checks like below? You can use the nice formatting of C++14:

```cpp
unsigned int ConvertRGBAToBGRA(unsigned int v) {
  unsigned char r = (v)&0xFF;
  unsigned char g = (v >> 8) & 0xFF;
  unsigned char b = (v >> 16) & 0xFF;
  unsigned char a = (v >> 24) & 0xFF;
  return (a << 24) | (r << 16) | (g << 8) | b;
};

TEST(ConvertRGBAToBGRATest, Test1) {
  EXPECT_EQ(ConvertRGBAToBGRA(0x12'34'56'78), 0x12'78'56'34);
  EXPECT_EQ(ConvertRGBAToBGRA(0x12'78'56'34), 0x12'34'56'78);
  EXPECT_EQ(ConvertRGBAToBGRA(0x11'11'11'11), 0x11'11'11'11);
  EXPECT_EQ(ConvertRGBAToBGRA(0x00'00'00'00), 0x00'00'00'00);
  EXPECT_EQ(ConvertRGBAToBGRA(0xAa'Bb'Cc'Dd), 0xAa'Dd'Cc'Bb);

  EXPECT_EQ(ConvertRGBAToBGRA(ConvertRGBAToBGRA(0x12'34'56'78)), 0x12'34'56'78);
  EXPECT_EQ(ConvertRGBAToBGRA(ConvertRGBAToBGRA(0x12'78'56'34)), 0x12'78'56'34);
  EXPECT_EQ(ConvertRGBAToBGRA(ConvertRGBAToBGRA(0x11'11'11'11)), 0x11'11'11'11);
  EXPECT_EQ(ConvertRGBAToBGRA(ConvertRGBAToBGRA(0x00'00'00'00)), 0x00'00'00'00);
  EXPECT_EQ(ConvertRGBAToBGRA(ConvertRGBAToBGRA(0xAa'Bb'Cc'Dd)), 0xAa'Bb'Cc'Dd);
}
```

Live example: https://godbolt.org/z/eEajYYYsf

You could also define a [custom matcher](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sfJobi4b_pw&t=2783s) and use `EXPECT_THAT` macro:

```
// A custom matcher for comparing BGRA and RGBA.
MATCHER_P(IsBgraOf, n, "") {
  return ((n & 0xFF000000) == (arg & 0xFF000000)) &&
         ((n & 0x00FF0000) == ((arg << 16) & 0x00FF0000)) &&
         ((n & 0x0000FF00) == (arg & 0x0000FF00));
}


TEST(ConvertRGBAToBGRATest, WithExpectThat) {
  EXPECT_THAT(ConvertRGBAToBGRA(0x12'34'56'78), IsBgraOf(0x12'34'56'78));
  EXPECT_THAT(ConvertRGBAToBGRA(0x12'78'56'34), IsBgraOf(0x12'78'56'34));
  EXPECT_THAT(ConvertRGBAToBGRA(0xAa'Bb'Cc'Dd), IsBgraOf(0xAa'Bb'Cc'Dd));
  EXPECT_THAT(ConvertRGBAToBGRA(0x00'00'00'00), IsBgraOf(0x00'00'00'00));
  EXPECT_THAT(ConvertRGBAToBGRA(0x11'11'11'11), IsBgraOf(0x11'11'11'11));
}
```

Live example: https://godbolt.org/z/P4EcW19s9

Comment: This is almost what I needed except for the fact that the tests fail. The logic is correct somehow `EXPECT_EQ` macro in GTest does not seem to understand the bitwise comparison

Comment: I can get around the gtest constraint of `EXPECT_EQ` by collecting the values in `unsigned int`s before comparison

Comment: "somehow EXPECT_EQ macro in GTest does not seem to understand the bitwise comparison": what do you mean? What did you try and what was the issue?

Comment: @TheWaterProgrammer I added a solution with custom matchers.

Answer (score 0):

You can split the value in four bytes by mapping to an array via a pointer. Then swap the bytes.

```
uint8_t* pV= reinterpret_cast<uint8_t*>(&V);
uint8_t Swap= pV[1]; pV[1]= pV[3]; pV[3]= Swap;
```

Comment: Sorry, I did not understand this. Where have you called `ConvertRGBAToBGRA` here to test it?

Comment: @TheWaterProgrammer: I am not testing anything !?!

Comment: You can't use `static_cast` for casting between unrelated types, you need `reinterpret_cast` instead. And there is no guarantee this will work anyway, since the only type you can safely cast to for accessing bytes like this is `(unsigned) char*`, which `uint8_t*` is not guaranteed to be an alias for.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: this is not intended to be portable. Anyway, in any environment where RGBA is used, that represents four eight bits bytes. There is no need to be more orthodox than the Pope.

Comment: Isn't the pope catholic?