# How to replace manual bit manipulation by bit_permute_step

Tags: bit-manipulation, bit

How can I do replace the following manual logic by http://programming.sirrida.de/perm_fn.html#bit_permute_step ?

```
 unsigned int ConvertRGBAToBGRA(unsigned int v) {
    unsigned char r = (v)& 0xFF;
    unsigned char g = (v >> 8) & 0xFF;
    unsigned char b = (v >> 16) & 0xFF;
    unsigned char a = (v >> 24) & 0xFF;
    return (a << 24) | (r << 16) | (g << 8) | b;
};
```

Is there a better way to do the above using http://programming.sirrida.de/perm_fn.html#bit_permute_step ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, namely:

```
return bit_permute_step(v, 0x000000ff, 16);
```

The bits of `v` indicated by the mask `0x000000ff` contain the `r` component, `bit_permute_step` will exchange them with the corresponding bits 16 (the distance parameter) places to the left, which corresponds to the `b` component of `v`. So `bit_permute_step(v, 0x000000ff, 16)` will swap the `r` with the `b`, and hence turn RGBA into BGRA (and also BGRA into RGBA, because a swap is its own inverse).

This could also be found via the permutation calculator: http://programming.sirrida.de/calcperm.php

Use the indices `16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31` (source indices) and disable bit-group moving.

---

A C++ implementation (also usable as C code) of `bit_permute_step` for 32-bit integers could be:

```
uint32_t bit_permute_step(uint32_t x, uint32_t m, uint32_t shift) {
    uint32_t t;
    t = ((x >> shift) ^ x) & m;
    x = (x ^ t) ^ (t << shift);
    return x;
}
```

Comment: Stupid question: Is the method `bit_permute_step` available in C++ ?

Comment: @TheWaterProgrammer I think the code on that page is already C++, isn't it?

Comment: That was stupid question. I got the point a bit late